# Creating an index from a list of words in Python (to vectorise words)

Tags: python, list, indexing, nlp, set

So I have a long list of words called word_list (that contains duplicates) and also have a set word_set that is just the word_list but without duplicates.

```
word_list = ['this','start','wonderland','amaze','this',.....]
word_set = set(word_list)
```

I also have a function that takes the word_list as input (raw_text):

```
def CBOW(raw_text, window_size=2):
   data = []
   for i in range(window_size, len(raw_text) - window_size):
       context = [raw_text[i - window_size], raw_text[i - (window_size - 1)], raw_text[i + (window_size - 1)], raw_text[i + window_size]]
       target = raw_text[i]
       data.append((context, target))

   return data

# The returned data has the form: [(['this', 'start', 'amaze', 'this'], 'wonderland'), .....]
```

It returns the corresponding words within the window size of a word (here it is wonderland)

I would like to instead have this return the **index** of those words from word_set:

For example, instead of

```
[(['this', 'start', 'amaze', 'this'], 'wonderland'), .....]
```

I would want

```
[(['0', '1', '2', '0'], 'wonderland'), .....] (as 'this' is a duplicate value so has index 0 )
```

Could anyone help me with this task?

For testing I have put a more comprehensive word_list here (along with my function) https://pastebin.com/EuS20u60

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that should be mentioned :)

1. `set()` object is supposed to mimic the set in math, so there is no index number accompanied with each member of the list. The only relation between an `element` and the `set` is **membership**.
2. When I ran the program I saw the function has nothing to do with the second argument `window_size` (creates a fixed-length context for totally different window_sizes). There is a similar function in the official `PyTorch` tutorial for doing the same job which I highly recommend you to take a look at.

Finally, if you are going to use words indices I suggest converting `word_set` object to a `list` object which already has `index()` method. The following is my implementation:

```
word_list = ['this','start','wonderland','amaze','this','read', 'instal', 'instruct', 'nis', '2004', 'nav', '2004', 'prior', 'latsni', 'still', 'end', 'result', 'junk', 'rawtfos', 'whi', 'instal', 'ina', 'type', 'softwar', 'instal', 'krow', 'proper', 'norton', 'tcudorp', '3', 'latsni', 'either', 'eno', 'norton', 'product', 'neither', 'krow', 'latsni', 'mcafe', 'anti', 'virus', '8', '2', 'comput', 'owner', 'sinc', 'purchas', 'mcafe', 'anti', 'virus', '8', 'instal']
word_set = set(word_list)
list_of_word_set = list(word_set) 
def CBOW(raw_text, window_size=2):
   data = []
   for i in range(window_size, len(raw_text) - window_size):
       context = [raw_text[i - window_size], raw_text[i - (window_size - 1)], raw_text[i + (window_size - 1)], raw_text[i + window_size]]
       context = [list_of_word_set.index(item) for item in context]
       target = raw_text[i]
       data.append((context, target)) 
   return data
CBOW(word_list, 10)
```

output:

```
[([11, 27, 21, 25], 'nav'),
 ([27, 5, 25, 0], '2004'),
 ...
```